# Intellij IDEA: cannot resolve method but can invoke

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

Recently I found that a method in a `jsp` file was written in red, which indicated that the method cannot be resolved by Intellij IDEA. However, when I debug the program, the method can ruturn normally. I guess it's because Intellij IDEA doesn
t know the method  truly exist. What should I do to find out the root of the problem?

[image]

Comment: Check the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/working-with-module-dependencies.html), you need to have `jsp-api.jar` and `servlet-api.jar` from your web container added there.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I added those two files from tomcat8.5/lib in module dependencies, however the word is still in red.